# Computing an equation that is a entered as a string

Tags: string, math, python-3.x, equation

I have to write multiple functions to solve a math puzzle. One of the functions takes in one side of the equation and computes the answer. The equation is entered as a string. I have created variables in order to continue counting numbers so that 22 is 22 and not 2,2 etc. When this function is run it prints -4. The parameter Blackout is set to 22-11*4. I'm confused as to what the issue is and the reason that I am getting -4. Perhaps the equation is being read backwards and jumping over some numbers?

```
def compute(Blackout):
numberBuild = ""
operator = ""
prev = 0
total = 0
for i in range (0 , len(Blackout)):
    current = Blackout[i]

    if current.isdigit():
        numberBuild = current
    else:
        operator = current

    if prev == 0 and operator != "":
        prev = numberBuild
        numberBuild = ""

    if prev != 0 and operator != "":
        if operator == "+":
            total = total + int(prev)
        elif operator == "-":
            total = total - int(prev)
        elif operator == "x":
            total = total * int(prev)
        elif operator == "/":
            total = total / int(prev)
    prev = 0
    i + 1

print(total)
```

Comment: Good grief, half of your class must have asked this question today...

Comment: Yeah, we jumped way past what we've been doing. The problem is not that I don't understand the concept, I have an issue with actually executing it.

Comment: 1. you have `x` in code and `*` in string, 2. how you handle operation priorities ? (so `*,/` is executed before `+,-`) most people use tree structures for this, I would use `(,)` functions ... 3. have you even try to debug? (breakpoint/trace) 4. there are some questions about this here already search for mathematical expression evaluation ...